# adobe flex user input must contain a "/" character

Tags: apache-flex, input, special-characters

In my project I have an user input, the first 4 characters should be number, and the fifth character must be `/`, is there a way to control this?

I am using Adobe Flash builder 4.6. I only know use restrict for number input.

**EDIT1**: 
After following Timofei's solution, I modified my source code as followings, but it not take effect, only notifying user "This field is required". Whatever I input in the textbox, no warning there, is it some wrong with my code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<viewer:BaseWidget xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:viewer="com.esri.viewer.*"
               right="450" bottom="175" width="320" height="450" widgetConfigLoaded="init()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[                       
        import mx.controls.Alert;       
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;            

        public function handleEvent():void
        {
            mx.controls.Alert.show("bq no input: " + attr_bqNo.text)    
        }                                   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:RegExpValidator id="validator" expression="^\d\{4\}/" noMatchError="Error text here" source="{attr_bqNo}" property="text" 
                        trigger="{attr_bqNo}" triggerEvent="change"/>
</fx:Declarations>
    <s:TextInput id="attr_bqNo" x="41" y="29" width="212"/>


<viewer:WidgetTemplate id="attributesearch"
                       width="320" height="450">
    <viewer:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout/>
    </viewer:layout>
    <s:Label x="41" y="15" width="132" height="15" text="BQ No."/>      
    <s:Label x="40" y="59" width="150" height="16" text="Contract No."/>
    <s:TextInput id="attr_contractNo" x="41" y="73" width="213"/>
    <s:Label x="40" y="146" text="Drain Name"/>
    <s:TextInput id="attr_drainName" x="40" y="159" width="213"/>
    <s:Label x="40" y="189" text="Project/Contract Title"/>
    <s:TextInput id="attr_projectTitle" x="40" y="203" width="213"/>        
    <s:Label x="40" y="323" text="Location (Road Name)"/>
    <s:TextInput id="attr_roadName" x="40" y="337" width="213"/>
    <s:Button id="attr_ok" x="68" y="367" label="Ok" click = "handleEvent()"/>
    <s:Button id="attr_clear" x="156" y="367" label="Clear"/>

  </viewer:WidgetTemplate>  
</viewer:BaseWidget>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `RegExpValidator`.

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <mx:RegExpValidator id="validator" expression="^\d\{4\}/" noMatchError="Error text here" source="{input}" property="text"
                trigger="{input}" triggerEvent="change"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:TextInput id="input"/>
```

[image: Example]

Read about [validators](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60efb-7fdd.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply, it still not work for me, probably because of my code issue. I have posted my code in the EDIT1 session, please advise me.

Comment: @user30643 Unfortunately, I don't see any problem with your code. I replaced WidgetTemplate with a Form, and it works fine for me.

Comment: thanks it works to me now, just curious can use RegExpValidator restrict the last 4 number and the last fifth is '/'?

Comment: @user30643 you're welcome. To be sure, do you want the input to look like "blablabla5432/"?

Comment: yes I want the input look link "abcdeblah/1234", thanks!

Comment: The expression would be: expression="/\d\{4\}$" (slash before digits) or expression="\d\{4\}/$" (slash after digits)

Comment: Thanks Timofei, is it possible that the number of digits is a variable? Since in my case the number of digits after slash may change.

Comment: @user30643 Sure. expression="/\d+$". Matches slash + any number of digits (1 or more) in the end of line